# doesnt print the value even if i initialize variable outside of function

Tags: javascript

I have a function below and i set username outside the function but I can get the value inside of it but not outside. Why is that? Example shown below. I am trying to print it outside or call it so it returns that value

```
var username
Auth.loggedInUser().then(function (user){
   username = user.username
   console.log(username) <--- this will print the username   
});
console.log(username) <--- this will print undefined
```

Also if i try the below it returns a promise in console that isnt just the username

```
var username = Auth.loggedInUser().then(function (user){
   return user.username
});
console.log(username) <--- this will Promise {$$state: Object}$$state: Object__proto__: Object
```

How can i go about just getting the raw username when calling it?

Comment: `console.log(username)` outside of the async call is running before your async call completes.

Comment: Impossible. Basically you order a pizza and soon as you hang up the phone you expect to eat it.

Comment: Got it, im not sure the code required to achieve this, im struggling, I get the concept, but maybe im not clear.

Comment: This is what i have so far;

      `function getUserName(callback) {
          Auth.loggedInUser().then(function (user){
          callback( user.name)
        });
      }`

Comment: `var username;
      getUserName(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
        username = result
      })
      console.log(username)` But as you can see result will print the value but username will still be undfined. How can i set this result value to a variable i can use outside of these functions. @JoshBeam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because you are using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which is asynchronous. It hadn't been fulfilled (where you set user.username as username) when `console.log(username)` was called. You can check the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/z1sh4k1u/).

```
var username = 'Rose';
new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve('Jack');
})
.then(name => {
  username = name;
  console.log('A:' + username);
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('B:' + username);
})
console.log('C:' + username);

// result:
// C:Rose
// A:Jack
// B:Jack
```

**UPDATE: I updated an await/sync solution, please [check](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/75rymgn8/).**

```
(async () => {
  const result = await axios.get('/echo/html/'); // axios.get returns a Promise object
  const status = result.status; // you wait until result is fulfilled
  console.log(status); // in this way, your get what you want.
})();
```

Comment: I am having trouble trying to get the value using my code. I get the idea but i dont know how to code it

Comment: Not sure what your use case is, but generally, callback should do the trick for you.

Comment: I went ahead and did that strategy and it worked, but how can i save the result to a variable outside of the callback? It will still show undefined.

Comment: This is what i have so far;

      `function getUserName(callback) {
          Auth.loggedInUser().then(function (user){
          callback( user.name)
        });
      }`
       
`var username;
      getUserName(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
        username = result
      })
      console.log(username)` But as you can see result will print the value but username will still be undfined. How can i set this result value to a variable i can use outside of these functions. @JoshBeam

Comment: You have to wait until your Promise object fulfilled. If you insist on writing like a synchronous way, await/async should be used which appears to be an overkill in your case, I think.

Comment: Btw, await/sync only works since ES2017.

Answer (score 0):

This obiously won't work, because you're using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which is running asynchronously. That means at the moment Javascript is running the second line with `console.log(username)`, the Promise isn't resolved yet and it prints `undefined`.

If you want to use the value of `username` you have to wait until the Promise resolves, for example invoking a method inside your `then`-method which takes the username as an arugment and is doing something with it.